# Setting up Wekan on Windows Server 2012 R2 (issue with 127.0.0.1)

Tags: localhost, windows-server-2012-r2

**Target Result:** To set up [Wekan](https://wekan.github.io/) on Windows Server 2012 R2 and remotely access it

**Current Status:** Currently the site is now up and running if I access it inside the server via this URL http://localhost:3000

**The Issue:** The site is up, I can access the site using localhost:3000, but when I tried to access 127.0.0.1:3000 I am just getting a blank page but the tab title and icon is showing correctly. I can't also access the site remotely using its IP address.

**Things tried but didn't work:**

- Run this command to CMD: `netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1`
- Update the hosts file from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and uncommented the line `127.0.0.1       localhost`

**Other infos:**

- When I tried to access http://localhost and http://127.0.0.1 both are showing same result (IIS Windows Server page)
- When I ping localhost it replies from ::1: (from my research this is the equivalent of 127.0.0.1 in IPv6, I might be wrong)
- When I ping 127.0.0.1 it replies from 127.0.0.1:

*Please help or give me hints why localhost:3000 and 127.0.0.1:3000 is not showing the same result when accessed via browser.*